# Error when calling methods between two services (triggered by init)

Tags: plugin-development, services

I have two Services in my plugin. `MyPluginService` is the "main" service, and `MyPlugin_OtherService` accomplishes some other tasks (when it is occasionally needed).

There is an `init` method in `MyPluginService` which starts a chain of events, and under certain circumstances will call a method in `MyPlugin_OtherService`.

#### MyPluginService

```
public function init() {
    parent::init();
    if ("conditions are met") {
        craft()->myPlugin_otherService->methodInOtherService();
    }
}

public function methodInMainService() {
    // ...
}
```

#### MyPlugin_OtherService

```
public function methodInOtherService() {
    craft()->myPlugin->methodInMainService();
}
```

While the method in `MyPlugin_OtherService` is being run, it will refer *back* to a method in `MyPluginService`. This is where the error is triggered:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::methodInMainService()

I don't understand why it's not recognizing that call to the main service method. Hasn't the main service already been initialized before this point? There is a lot about "lazy loading" that I don't understand, maybe this falls in that knowledge gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service’s `init()` function gets called immediately after it is loaded – and before Yii has had a chance to remember that `craft()->myPlugin` should return the service instance.

Take a look at [these two lines](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/base/CModule.php#L393-L394) from CModule::getComponent() (the method that the magic getter invokes when you call `craft()->somePluginName`):

```
$component->init();
return $this->_components[$id]=$component;
```

So when `MyPlugin_OtherService::methodInOtherService()` tries to refer back to `craft()->myPlugin`, `craft()->myPlugin` has not yet been assigned to the service instance, which results in the PHP fatal error you’re getting.

I can propose a change that would fix this:

```
$this->_components[$id] = $component;
$component->init();
return $component;
```

…but I’m not sure what the implications would be for that.

You might just need to question whether it’s so important for this code to be running from `init()` as opposed to another function that you’d have to invoke manually. Having it in `init()` could lead to other unexpected consequences as well.

Comment: To be clear, I'm talking about two services within the same plugin.

Comment: @LindseyD Sorry, totally missed that. Updated my answer.

Comment: +1 for moving it out of init() and explicitly calling it.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I've got it in the `init` because it's a pretty big piece of the puzzle, and many other facets of the plugin depend on the data generated there. But, if I'm understanding you correctly, you are suggesting that I remove that method call from the init, and instead simply call it manually before any possible scenario where the data might be needed? Then I would probably have to set an `alreadyRun` property in my main service class so I can easily determine if the process has been run. Does that sound like a better solution to you?

Comment: Any reason you don’t put the code in your main plugin class’s `init()` function? That’s probably safer.

Comment: Ah, so I can just move it to the `init` of `MyPlugin.php`? Would all of the necessary Service files have been loaded by that point?

Comment: @LindseyD yep, it will get called at the beginning of each request, and all your services will be available at that point.

Comment: Awesome, then that's my new plan! Thanks Brandon!