# Calling a method from a service in another plugin from an event

Tags: plugin-development

I'm having a problem calling a service method from another plugin when hooking into the `beforeSend` event in the [ContactForm](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm) plugin. I have the code below in a super simple plugin called `ContactFormExtra` to catch if someone wants to also subscribe to our newsletter when they fill in the contact form. I have another subscribe plugin setup with it's service class having the methods to do the subscribing - which also handles a simpler subscribe form without the contact form fields. Any ideas on how this could work - or do I need to put all the subscribe stuff again into the `ContactFormExtra` plugin?

This follows the example on GitHub for `pixelandtonic/ContactForm`

When trying to subscribe on the contact form, I get this error:

```
Craft\ContactFormExtraPlugin and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "_getSettings".
```

Looks like it's trying to call the Subscribe plugin's functions from the ContactFormExtra plugin?

If I don't choose to subscribe and submit the form, then the `Subscribe` plugin service call is skipped, moving on to the calls on the `ContactFormExtra` plugin's service. Then I get this error:

```
Property "Craft\WebApp.contactformextra" is not defined.
```

Simple `ContactFormExtra` plugin code: 
(`plugins/contactformextra/ContactFormExtraPlugin.php`)

```
class ContactFormExtraPlugin extends BasePlugin
{
  public function init()
  {
    craft()->on('contactForm.beforeSend', function(ContactFormEvent $event) {
      $message = $event->params['message'];
      $subscribe = craft()->request->getPost('subscribe');
      $attribs = $message->getAttributes();
      if ($subscribe == 1) {
        $result = SubscribeService::subscribe($attribs['fromEmail']);
      }
      // save the record
      $attribs = $message->getAttributes();
      $attribs['subscribe'] = $subscribe;
      $enquiryModel = craft()->contactformextra->newEnquiry($attribs);
      craft()->contactformextra->saveEnquiry($enquiryModel);
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

`ContactFormExtra` plugin service code: 
(`plugins/contactformextra/services/ContactFormExtraService.php`)

```
class ContactFormExtraService extends BaseApplicationComponent
{

    public function newEnquiry($attributes) {
      // do stuff here
    }

    public function saveEnquiry(ContactFormExtra_EnquiryModel &$model) {
      // do stuff here
    }

}
```

`Subscriber` plugin:
(`plugins/subscribe/services/SubscribeService.php`)

```
class SubscribeService extends BaseApplicationComponent
{
  protected $settings;

  private function _getSettings()
  {
    $plugin_settings = craft()->plugins->getPlugin('subscribe')->getSettings();
    $this->settings = $plugin_settings;
  }

  public function subscribe($email)
  {
    $this->_getSettings();
    // do the subscribing here...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capitalization matters when you're calling services. Try updating this line:

`$enquiryModel = craft()->contactformextra->newEnquiry($attribs);`

to this:

`$enquiryModel = craft()->contactFormExtra->newEnquiry($attribs);`

and make sure you update that across **all** the places where you're calling that service. Try that, and post the results. I'll take another look if you're still seeing the issue, which may still be there; just grabbing at low-hanging fruit right now. :)

Comment: Thanks so much Taylor that was it - what a silly mistake! I think maybe for some reason I thought the service name was meant to be all lower like the plugin folder name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you're getting the error message you are, but I see a couple of issues with your code that should be addressed first.

1. You're calling `SubscribeService::subscribe` statically and the method is not declared as a static method in SubscribeService (`public function subscribe($email)`).
2. Generally you don't want expose static methods in the service layer of your plugin.  If that's the only service your plugin has, then you should be able to do a `craft()->subscribe->subscribe($attribs['fromEmail'])` from your `ContactFormExtra` plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Brad - my bad on the static thing. If I keep that method as public and change the `ContactFormExtra` plugin to call the method via `craft()->subscribe->subscribe($attribs['fromEmail'])` I get the following error:

`Property "Craft\WebApp.subscribe" is not defined. `

Could this be related to the `init()` limitations discussed [here](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/847/error-when-calling-methods-between-two-services-triggered-by-init)?

ie. the service in the `Subscribe` plugin isn't registered yet?

Comment: I've updated my question - firstly moving the subscribe form field stuff into the `ContactFormExtra` plugin so I don't edit the `ContactForm` plugin. I've added the 2nd part of the `ContactFormExtra` functionality which is to save the enquiry and I've used  `craft()->contactformextra->...` to make the call and I still run into an error when submitting the form without ticking subscribe - `Property "Craft\WebApp.contactformextra" is not defined.`